# In Terraform, how do I specify the AWS security group for a spot fleet request?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I successfully generated an AWS spot fleet using [spot_fleet_request](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/spot_fleet_request.html) resource. However, the EC2 instances it creates uses a `default` security group, but I don't see an option to specify the security group for the resource. When creating a spot fleet request via the AWS console, there is an option to specify the security group.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They mention it in the documentation of the `spot_fleet_request`:

> launch_specification - Used to define the launch configuration of the spot-fleet request. Can be specified multiple times to define different bids across different markets and instance types.
>   Note: This takes in similar but not identical inputs as aws_instance. There are limitations on what you can specify. See the list of officially supported inputs in the reference documentation. Any normal aws_instance parameter that corresponds to those inputs may be used and it have a additional parameter iam_instance_profile_arn takes aws_iam_instance_profile attribute arn as input.

essentially the `launch_specification` can take in any parameter referenced in [the SpotFleetLaunchSpecification in the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_SpotFleetLaunchSpecification.html). For example: `vpc_security_group_ids`.

You can also always check the go code of the [aws provider on github](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/aws/resource_aws_spot_fleet_request.go#L62) to check what options are available.

Comment: Yep, I missed the `Note: This takes in similar but not identical inputs as aws_instance.` Thanks.